# Rails Error: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Total noob mistake probably, Sorry, I am quite new to rails

Here is my code

```
#<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>ConveySation</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="brand"> ConveySation</a>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
    </div>
      <%= link_to "HomePage", root_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
       </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
     <br class="clear" />
  </div>
<%yield%>
</head>
</html>
<%end%>
```

and i get title error code
Please Help!!

Answer (score 3):

Remove the last statement `<%end%>` from your code. Thats causing the error. In your code, there is no block to end. 
And while you are at it, correct your html code as

```
<%yield%>
</head>
```

to

```
<%yield%>
</body>
```

Also, correct on your html syntax.
HTML Elements should be arranged like  `<div> ..<ul> ..</ul> </div>`
and not `<div>..<ul>..</div> </ul>`

Comment: @user3303559 Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue.